# Objective-C　JSONファイルをサーバーにPOSTしてデータ登録をする方法

Tags: objective-c, php, json

サーバーからJSONをNSURLSessionで取得して
一覧に表示するところまで作成しました。

次にサーバーにJSONデータを送信するところで迷ってます。

DBから結果を取得後のサーバーにデータを
送信する場合は、どういった処理をすればいいのでしょうか。
データの中は複数件あります。

出来ればPHPで受け取って処理する
方法もわかれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

PHP側では、
php://inputで処理をするところまでは、
わかりました。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: データの形式を指定してください。回答方法が変わってくるので。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
なんとか解決致しました。

Answer (score 2):

環境やバージョンによりますが、一般的な送信とPHPでの受け取りです。

objective-c

```
NSString *jsonRequest =@"{\"test\":{\"item1\":\"item\",\"item2\":\"item\"}}";

NSData *requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"接続先URL"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];

NSURLResponse *resp;
NSError *err;


NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
if (result != nil) {
    NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data %@",res);
}
```

PHP

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
//省略
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決出来ました。